# C# Проблема с TcpListener

Tags: c#, websocket

Запросы к серверу проходят через раз, вот код сервера. Почему так происходит?

```
    public Server(int port)
    {
        Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        Listener.Start();

        while(true)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ClientThread, Listener.AcceptTcpClient());
        }
    }
    void ClientThread(Object StateInfo)
    {
        new Client((TcpClient)StateInfo);
    }
```

Вот метод Main:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int MaxThreadsCount = Environment.ProcessorCount * 100;
        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(MaxThreadsCount, MaxThreadsCount);
        ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(2, 2);
        new Server(8080);
    }
```

Вот скрин запросов:
[image: a busy cat]

PS: процессор 8-и ядерный, так что число процессов может доходить до 800

UPD: Написал Console.Clear() и проблема исчезла, кто-нибудь сможет объяснить почему?

```
    void ClientThread(Object StateInfo)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        new Client((TcpClient)StateInfo);
    }
```

Comment: это зависит от браузера. А в чем собственно бесспокойство (проблема)? Может браузер создаёт 4 сокета что бы обеспечить "быстрый" интернет.

Comment: @nick_n_a , проблема в том, что почему-то иногда браузер выдает, что соединение сброшено при частом обновлении страницы

Comment: Попробуйте http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724596/how-can-i-use-a-threadpool-to-process-each-connection-in-a-new-thread этот пример. Я тоже пытался сам принимать через Accept и ловил такую же ошибку. Сделал через pool как в примере.

Comment: @nick_n_a , попробовал, но проблема осталась(стала чуть реже), прикрепил скриншот

Comment: Покажите класс Client - наверняка же ошибка в нем...